# Sql server 2005 date function

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, date

I would like to know how to get no. of days using getdate() & 
existing dates in other table, where that table contains multiple records, ie i would like
to know the jobs posted 5 days back or 10 days back or 15 days back. I have written the
query like

```
declare @q1 datetime;
select cdate from jobposting where cdate like (select cdate)
select datediff ( dd, q1, getdate())
```

where q1 must store all the dates in jobposting table, but i cannot get correct answer.

Or i also tried like

```
select datediff ( dd, select cdate from jobposting, getdate())
```

thanking U in Advance.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, there are two common ways to achieve what you request:

First, using datediff() as Kim suggests.

The other is to work out what the date is 5 days ago, and then compare the dates in the table to it (which should be faster than DateDiff if the column is indexed):

```
declare @cutoff datetime;
set @cutoff = dateadd(day, -5, getdate());
select * from jobposting where cdate >= @cutoff;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's probably better -- calculate the oldest date first, and then lean on the index to get the relevant matches. +1.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, assuming 5 days. @days could be asked for as a parameter to a stored procedure to make it flexible:

```
DECLARE @days int
SET @days = 5

SELECT cdate
FROM jobposting
WHERE datediff(d, cdate, getdate()) <= @days
```

Comment: +1: I think this one answers the question properly and how i would have coded it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but this should return all jobposting rows where cdate is 5 days old or <strike>younger</strike> older.

```
SELECT *
FROM jobposting
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, cdate, GETDATE()) >= 5
```

Comment: This will get everything 5 days or older. I admit that the question is a little ambiguous though as to which side of 5 days Lakshmi wanted to return :)

Comment: @Matt: Agh, and I was so sure I got it right :) Edited, thanks!